# Fatal error: Call to undefined function printer_open()

Tags: php, printing, xampp, wamp, htdocs

I'm trying to print some string using PHP, i'm using the PHP print functions:

```
$printer = ("HP LaserJet Professional P1102");
$handler= printer_open($printer);
$content="Test Content";
printer_write($handler, $content);
printer_close($handler);
```

but I got that error :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function printer_open() in C:\xampp\htdocs\print.php on line 12
```

after googling it i found that i must add the **php_printer.dll** to the extensions file in php and add it's extension to the **php.ini** file, then restarting the server services, all of that accomplished but still getting that error.
p.s. I've tried it on **WAMP** and **XAMPP**

Answer (score 1):

I think solution would be extension location.php_printer extension should be stored in c:\xampp\php\ext and not in c:\xampp\php. So move it to the ext-folder, and restart Apache.

Can you look into the error_log, which tells you, if it fails to load the module. You should also run a phpinfo(), which shows up all loaded modules, you must find the printer extensions there.

I hope it may resolve your issue.

Comment: but i don't find any loaded modules about printer extensions in phpinfo()

Comment: [Thu Oct 03 14:55:11.606850 2013] [:error] [pid 47980:tid 832] [client ::1:55008] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function printer_open() in C:\\wamp\\www\\print\\print.php on line 12, referer: http://localhost/print/
[Thu Oct 03 14:55:11.606850 2013] [:error] [pid 47980:tid 832] [client ::1:55008] PHP Stack trace:, referer: http://localhost/print/
[Thu Oct 03 14:55:11.606850 2013] [:error] [pid 47980:tid 832] [client ::1:55008] PHP   1. {main}() C:\\wamp\\www\\print\\print.php:0, referer: http://localhost/print/